# Compute isovist from OSM buildings

Tags: postgis, visibility

I'm using PostGIS with OSM table of buildings.

How can I compute isovist from single location point while only the buildings (represented as geom's) are the obstacles?

Comment: there's a [Space Syntax plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/spacesyntax/) for QGIS, although I've not had a chance to try it.. I think  Isovists are used in Space Syntax, so it might be worth a look.

Comment: @StevenKay Thanks, But I need to run it as regular query from server software program. So I need it as pure PostGIS script... Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].